# Compiler issue with Qt 5.4.1

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw

I am now using Qt 5.4.1, the latest version of Qt. But just now I encounter some bug. I guess it's because I use the wrong compiler.

By many document's suggestion, we are supposed to use the mingw compiler for qt. But, no MingW detected in my computer is suited for the Qt 5.4.1. Only the **Microsoft Visual C++ compiler 12.0 x86_amd64**  is ok.

I have install two mingw in my computer(one of which is 4.8.1 I guess).   But none of them are suited for the qt5.4.1. Not the **gcc.exe** in **C:\MinGW\bin**, nor the **mingw32-gcc.exe** and **mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe** in **C:\MinGW\bin**

Also, I try the **gcc.exe** and **g++.exe** in **D:\GCC\gcc\bin**, but it's also the same.

Why is that?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: What exactly have you downloaded and installed? Because the Qt built with MinGW, contains the compatible MinGW compiler too: _Qt 5.4.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.1, 856 MB)_ if you installed one of the Visual Studio versions, you'll need the same Visual Studio version installed separately (Qt can't contain and install that too)